# Dockerfile cannot run cp command to move file inside container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Hi I am trying to download a file inside container and moving this file in specific location inside container.

```
RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar 
RUN cp gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/
RUN cp /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-defaults.conf
RUN echo "spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable true" > /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

But this is failing with the error as below:

```
Step 44/46 : RUN cp gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/
 ---> Running in 8c81d9871377
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c cp gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**EDIT-1**
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HyCq.png)

I have tried the solution mentioned and now I am getting the below error:

Removing intermediate container e885431017e8
Step 43/44 : COPY /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-defaults.conf
lstat opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template: no such file or directory

Comment: can you post the whole dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you download to the folder directly? and use COPY to copy files inside the container [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

```
RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar -P /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/
COPY /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

assumed: `/opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/`folder exists

Comment: I have tried above solution and it was a partial success. I was able to download the jar in mentioned location whereas, I was not able to copy the file as (No such File or directory)

Comment: that was the folder spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7 which was basically soft link not the real destination. I have got it corrected. Thanks for the help Buddy.

Answer (score 2):

do you have already the path `/opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/` in your container?

if not add this before `cp` command:

```
mkdir -p /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/
```

then try to copy like this:

```
cp gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar
```

after your edit:

you run `mkdir` and try to copy from it , that should not work since the folder is empty !!

Comment: Yes I have this path inplace, just wanted to add this jar too in the  /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/

Comment: See the updated image in the question. I tried what you suggested but still getting the same error.

Comment: it sems you make a dir and want to copy from it !! the folder is empty